# PHP calculate past dates from today

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce

I have created a PHP function that calculates how old a WordPress/WooCommerce order is. If the order is older than 90 days it should be canceled. The function used to work perfectly. However, since the new year 2020, it has stopped working. I would assume it's because the function gets confused about the year since -90 days from today is year 2019. How can I make the calculation work with the past years/2019?

I have tried playing with different date formats from the WordPress codex instead of mdy. However, this doesn't seem to do any difference.

```
function expire_after_x_days(){
    global $wpdb;
    // Get current time
    $today = date("m/d/y");

    // set time to expire
    $time_to_expire = "-90 days";
    $expiration_date = date("m/d/y", strtotime( $today . $time_to_expire));

    // Get orders with processing status
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' AND post_status = 'wc-processing'");

    if( !empty($result)) foreach ($result as $order){
        // Get order's time
        $order_time = get_the_time('m/d/y', $order->ID );

        // Compare order's time with current time
        if ( $order_time < $expiration_date ){

            // Update order status    
            $orders = array();
            $orders['ID'] = $order->ID;
            $orders['post_status'] = 'wc-cancelled';
            wp_update_post( $orders );
        }
    }
} 

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'expire_after_x_days' );
```

Comment: i tried you code local and all work...

Comment: @Simone Rossaini for me when I click a few times backend all of my orders get cancelled (also new ones from today). This just recently started after new years. I have checked plugin conflicts etc and the only solution to the issue I have come up with is to remove my code or figure out why the calculation of date goes wrong.

Comment: What does `get_the_time()` do?

Comment: @Qirel get_the_time() retrieve the time at which the post was written (copy/paste from WordPress codex). In this example, get_the_time get the date the order was created.

Comment: What is the name of the of the date-created field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot by running an `UPDATE` query with a `WHERE` clause, to only fetch those orders that are older than 90 days. No need to fetch them all and loop over the results.

You will need to set the `post_created` to the actual name of your column.

```
function expire_after_x_days() {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
                            SET post_status = 'wc-cancelled'
                            WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' 
                              AND post_status = 'wc-processing'
                              AND post_created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)");
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much. Solved issue and also improved code a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are treating those variables as DateTime instances, but they are strings. This `$order_time < $expiration_date` compares the strings alphabetically, not by their date meaning. Use DateTime class (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please change date format from **m/d/y** to **Y-m-d**. Please see below code.

you can also check manually by modify $order_time = '12/11/18';

```
function expire_after_x_days(){
        global $wpdb;
        // Get current time
        $today = date("Y-m-d");

        // set time to expire
        $time_to_expire = "-90 days";
        $expiration_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $today . $time_to_expire));

        // Get orders with processing status
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' AND post_status = 'wc-processing'");

        if( !empty($result)){
            foreach ($result as $order){
            // Get order's time
            $order_time = get_the_time('Y-m-d', $order->ID );
            // Compare order's time with current time
            //$order_time = '12/11/18';
                if ( $order_time < $expiration_date ){
                    //die("olde");
                        // Update order status    
                        $orders = array();
                        $orders['ID'] = $order->ID;
                        $orders['post_status'] = 'wc-cancelled';
                        wp_update_post( $orders );
                }else{
                    //echo 'not old date';die;
                }
            }
        }

} 
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'expire_after_x_days' );
```